# Why does this echo call overwrite existing text?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Consider the following CSV file:

```
jdbc.driverClassName,oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

jdbc.username,kshitiz
```

It has to be transformed into:

```
-Djdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver \

-Djdbc.username=kshitiz \
```

Given the following bash snippet:

```
while read l; do
    IFS=',' read -ra arr <<< "$l"
    echo '-D'${arr[0]}'='${arr[1]}' \'
done <properties.txt
```

Bash prints:

```
\jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 

\jdbc.username=kshitiz
```

What's going on here?

Comment: That depends on which `echo` you use, which in turn depends on your shell as most have `echo` as a build-in. Does replacing `echo STRING` with `printf '%s\n' STRING` fix your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  \jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
> ```

What your script has actually output is

1. `-Djdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`
2. a carriage return
3. `\` (note the space)
4. a newline

Why has your script printed a carriage return?  Because your input file does not have Unix-convention newlines, but has CRLFs instead, and the carriage return at the end of each line has been considered part of the second array variable.

Why is whitespace like a carriage return being appended to a variable by `read`?  Because you changed `IFS`.

Some words to the wise:

- Use `printf`, not `echo` — *especially*, as here, when you are passing `echo` things that look like command-line options and things with backslashes in.
- Diagnose these sorts of problems by passing the output through `hexdump -C`, `cat -v`, or `od -t c -t x1`.
- If you don't have `dos2unix`, it is easy to do the equivalent with `tr`, `sed`, or `perl`.